# I want to add a vertical line before and after the list tag. First list tag before vertical line not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I added a line using before concept, but the first list tag left sideline is missing. Error output is https://prnt.sc/pjilp5
I Wanted Output like this: https://prnt.sc/pjim1p

HTML Code:

```
    <div class="top-sm">
      <ul>
      <a href="#"><li><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></li></a>
      <a href="#"><li><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></li></a>
      <a href="#"><li><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></li></a>
      <a href="#"><li><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></li></a>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Style:

```
    .top-sm li{ display:inline-block; list-style:none;margin: 0;position:relative;padding: 15px 8px 0;}
    .top-sm li:before{content:""; position:absolute;top:0;right: 6px;width:1px;height: 55px;background: white;}
```

Comment: Your HTML is **invalid**. The `li` must be children of the `ul` and the links *inside* the `li`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your `HTML` its `not valid` HTML and for line you can use `border` property check below snippet.

```css
.top-sm li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 8px 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}

.top-sm li:last-child {
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-sm">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in">3</i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```